# How can I optionally embed one or more interfaces inside of a Typescript interface?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to define a type `D` that requires all fields of interface `A`, but optionally also embeds the fields of interface `B`, `C` or both.

Here is how I'm trying to define it:

```
interface A {
    a1: number;
    a2: number;
};

interface B {
    b1: number;
    b2: number;
};

interface C {
    c1: number;
    c2: number;
};

type D = A | (A & B) | (A & C) | (A & B & C);

let d: D;
d = {'a1': 1, 'a2': 2};
if ('c1' in d) {
    d.c1 = 123;
}
```

However, typescript doesn't seem to like this, and complains: *Property 'c1' does not exist on type 'never'.*

In case I've explained the above poorly, I want type D to be able to hold the following values:

```
{"a1": 1, "a2": 2}
{"a1": 1, "a2": 2, "b1": 3, "b2": 4}
{"a1": 1, "a2": 2, "c1": 5, "c2": 6}
{"a1": 1, "a2": 2, "b1": 3, "b2": 4, "c1": 5, "c2": 6}
```

But not:

```
{"a1": 1} // missing field a2
{"a1": 1, "a2": 2, "b2": 4} // missing field b1
{"a1": 1, "a2": 2, "c1": 5} // missing field c2
{"a2": 2, "b1": 3, "c2": 6} // missing fields a1, b2, c1
```

How can I do this in typescript?

Comment: Property 'c1' does not exist on type 'never', because you assign a string instead of number. Consider change the value to a number

Comment: I don't think you can do this. Because interfaces are inclusive, not exclusive, the compiler can't tell whether you have an A with some extra properties or an A & B that's missing something required. You'll have to be more specific to hint it appropriately. Maybe someone with a deeper knowledge of TS will prove me wrong though.

Comment: @ThemistoklisBogiatzoglou I've fixed the example, it should have been `d.c1 = 123;` instead of `d.c1 = '123';`, sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you notice, if you mouse over `d` on line 3 below, after the assignment on line 2

```
let d: D;
d = {'a1': 1, 'a2': 2};
if ('c1' in d) { // mouse over `d` here
  d.c1 = 123; // Property 'c1' does not exist on type 'never'.
}
```

typescript has smartly determined the `d` is actually type `A`.

But if you assign it to something that returns `D` and not a sub type, you will get no error:

```
let d: D;
d = {'a1': 1, 'a2': 2} as D; // cast
if ('c1' in d) {
  d.c1 = 123; // no error
}
```

or

```
function makeD(): D {
  return { a1: 1, a2: 2 };
}

let d: D;
d = makeD();
if ('c1' in d) {
  d.c1 = 123; // no error
}
```

In other words, typescritp's type awareness goes:

```
let d: D; // `d` is `D` (possibly unassigned)
d = {'a1': 1, 'a2': 2}; // `d` is assigned something that matches it's sub type `A`, so `d` is `A` after this
if ('c1' in d) { // 'c1' is not in `A` so `d` is never in side this if block
  d.c1 = 123; // Property 'c1' does not exist on type 'never'.
}
```

so you want to change it to:

```
let d: D; // `d` is `D` (possibly unassigned)
d = somthingThatIsD; // `d` is assigned (still `D`)
if ('c1' in d) { // 'c1' is in `D` so `d` is still `D`
  d.c1 = 123; // no error
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize my initial assignment caused typescript to pick type A, but that makes complete sense. Thanks for the great explanation!

Answer (score 1):

one option would be:

```
interface D extends A, Partial<B>, Partial<C> {}
```

or if you prefer using `type`:

```
type D = A & Partial<B> & Partial<C>;
```

(see https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm+XARgC5kQBXAWwCNoBuHPOAJhPOrqwF96tRJZEKAEKYGuKsVKUaUenmRUWU9rK48+0eEmQBhUfISS2MuXgRLjHbll7hNg5ABFkEAB6QQAEwDOaADTIAApwUGDAcAA2ADxCAHwBwaHh0TqxmMicNhEQYMieJI70nsgAvJgA5ITlJAQBlUzVyEzWwDDIABTlhuXIoHkAlPp4ngB0hqXIBEwAzPScQA)

`Partial` is a built-in thing from TypeScript that takes all of the properties from the passed in interface and makes them optional. This means though that you could have a situation where e.g. `c1` is defined, but `c2` isn't.

Comment: I know about `Partial`. It doesn't quite do what I want. As mentioned in my question, the following value should not be accepted by my type `D`: `{"a1": 1, "a2": 2, "b2": 4}` because it is missing field b1.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
interface A {
    a1: number;
    a2: number;
};

interface B {
    b1: number;
    b2: number;
};

interface C {
    c1: number;
    c2: number;
};

type AB = (A & B);
type AC = (A & C);
type ABC = (A & B & C);
type D = A | AB | AC | ABC;

let d: D;
d = {'a1': 1, 'a2': 2};
if ((d as AC).c1) {
    const ac = (d as AC);
    d = {...d, c1: ac.c1}
}
```

I think the major feature to leverage on here is the `as` keyword